# Artifactory - Failed to update stats with error couldn't find versionIDs for the given paths

Tags: artifactory

My Artifactory logs are showing the following errors with alarming frequency. The metadata service is up and healthy according to Artifactory, and aside from the log spam, it doesn't seem to be causing any problems. Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

`[jfrt ] [ERROR] [af10ed1c492f4e88] [s.MetadataEventServiceImpl:346] [art-exec-6 ] - Unable to send statistics event to Metadata Server. Caught exception: Failed executing api/v1/stats, with response code: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error and response message: {"cause":"Internal error while processing request","message":"Failed to update stats with error couldn't find versionIDs for the given paths: couldn't find versionIDs for the given paths"}`

- Artifactory 7.27.10, running in Kubernetes
- Using an external postgres 13 database
- Using s3 as the storage backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue (documented internally as META-1180). This has been fixed and is released with Artifactory 7.29. This version of Artifactory is scheduled for release sometime over the next few weeks.

Comment: Thank you! I'll keep an eye out for that release.